# Azure Mysql server connection with Azure Synpase Spark doesnt work

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse, azure-mysql-database

I´m trying to connect to an Azure Mysql database server to create a table from a Dataframe in Azure Synapse with Spark.

I have this url and this properties
All variables like jdbcXYZ are fulled with the correct values from the database

```
import java.util.Properties


val jdbc_url = s"jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/database=${jdbcDatabase};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=60;"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
```

And i try to write to the database with

```
spark.table("tabletemp").write.mode("append").jdbc(jdbc_url, "table", connectionProperties)
```

I also tried

```
df.write.format("jdbc").mode("append").option("url", jdbc_url).option("dbtable", jdbcDatabase).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).save()
```

And i´m always receiving the same error

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server
```

Do you know how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am very confident that this a config issue , you are not passing all correct value for all the properties . I quick scan makes me think that this is not correct .

> .option("dbtable", jdbcDatabase).

Comment: Hi, First thanks for your reply. I took that line from spark docs: spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html where it puts that option. Thanks!